# I was trying to record number of packets sent and packets received in this OMNet++ simulation

Tags: omnet++, simulator

the problem is

1. vector is not getting created
2. scalar values (totalMessagesReceived and totalMessagesSent) are not incrementing and is always 0.

[this is my .cc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm9PE.jpg)

[this is .ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT59N.jpg)

[this is file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImvJd.jpg)

please help as I'm beginner.

Comment: Please don't use code in pictures. It makes it very hard to try out the code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)